# Extract plain text from DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, dom

I got the selection information from:

```js
var childNodes = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.childNodes
```

The actual data will be:

```html
<p>
    Something I’ve not covered much so far is some of the newer parts of JavaScript. 
    That is, methods in ECMASscript 5 that are not so 
    <span class="mydict_highlighted">commonly</span>
    used due to browser support, and of course the new features in ECMAScript 6. 
    Today I want to take a look at the new Array methods in ES5, such as 
    <code class="highlighter-rouge">map</code>
    and 
    <code class="highlighter-rouge">filter</code>
    .
</p>
```

How could I extract the text only from the `childNodes`?

[image: inline]

Comment: Is the "actual data" shown what you have in the `childNodes` variable? What is your desired output from the input shown?

Answer (score 4):

### About `element.textContent`

Use `element.textContent` to get the text inside an HTML element with all descendant HTML tags stripped. If you wish, you can add `.trim()` to the end to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the returned text.

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.textContent.trim()
```

### About `element.innerText`

Alternatively, one can use the `element.innerText` property (once proprietary to IE, but later added to the web standards) to do *almost* the same thing. `textContent` will more closely match the actual string data stored inside your DOM nodes (it is essentially a concatenation of every text node), whereas `innerText` attempts to be more "helpful" by trying to mimic the style of the page, e.g. by omitting the text from `script`/`style` tags and visually hidden elements. The one you prefer will vary depending on the use case, but I find I use `textContent` the majority of the time. For more information, I would highly recommend you check out [this list of differences between the two properties on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText).

### Demo for `textContent`

```js
var element = document.getElementById('content')

console.log(element.textContent.trim())
```

```html
<div id="content">

<p>Something I’ve not covered much so far is some of the newer parts of JavaScript. That is, methods in ECMASscript 5 that are not so <span class="mydict_highlighted">commonly</span> used due to browser support, and of course the new features in ECMAScript 6. Today I want to take a look at the new Array methods in ES5, such as <code class="highlighter-rouge">map</code> and <code class="highlighter-rouge">filter</code>.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: While I generally prefer [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), this answer would be better if you also mentioned [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) and explained, *briefly*, the differences between the two.

Comment: Other than not copiously linking to documentation :-)... Looks good.